# TYPO3 extension "news": Custom fields on Fluid Template

Tags: typo3, fluid

I am using the extension News System, "news", and while changing the templates, I've noticed that while I can use things like `{newsItem.datetime}` or `{newsItem.uid}`, I cant use this with the custom fields i have created when extending the table `tx_news_domain_model_news`, like `{newsItem.mycustomfield}`

**Edit**: I have been pointed to [this url](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/Main/Tutorial/ExtendingNews/Index.html#extend-the-classes) and I've followed the instructions, but it's not working. This is my code

News.php

```
<?php
    class Tx_WedoExtendnews_Domain_Model_News extends Tx_News_Domain_Model_News {

        /**
        * @var string
        */
        protected $txWedoextendnewsLocation;

        public function getTxWedoextendnewsLocation() {
            return "this";
            return $this->txWedoextendnewsLocation;
        }
        public function getWedoextendnewsLocation() {
            return "that";
            return $this->txWedoextendnewsLocation;
        }
    }
?>
```

Since I wasn't getting anything, I changed the returning values to string literals, to see if the problem was in the class and method names, or the property. Im still not getting anything. I think the underscored might be playing tricks on my code.

My extension key is `wedo_extendnews` and the new field is `tx_wedoextendnews_location`. Any ideas where the error lies?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. To be able to access an object in fluid, you need the according setters in your model and maybe (not sure right now) an entry in the TCA.

If you want to access `{newsItem.mycustomfield}` you need an according setter in the model, like `public function getMycustomfield()` (note the `get` in `get<Myfuncname>`, it is mandatory).

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Could you please extend a little where and how to do it? I'm really new with Fluid Templates and i have no idea how to do this. I already set up a entry on the TCA.

Comment: and does this change when the field has underscores?